# Does Octopus Deploy talk to any other repos ( like maven, npm) other than nuGet?

Tags: java, maven, octopus-deploy

Octopus Deploy can talk to nuGet repository.

But, can it be integrated with Maven Repositories to poll the artifact from them?

How can we poll a java application artifact (WAR, JAR or EAR) file from a maven repo inside the Octopus Deploy and deploy it?

Comment: If you're interested - there's a UserVoice item with a similar suggestion: https://octopusdeploy.uservoice.com/forums/170787-general/suggestions/16649128-npm-and-bower-package-support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Only NuGet feedsare supported]
Source: http://docs.octopusdeploy.com/display/OD/Package+repositories#Packagerepositories-Usingexternalrepositories

However; you can push all sorts of packages to Octopus e.g.

- NuGet
- Tar
- Zip
- and more

(source: http://docs.octopusdeploy.com/display/OD/Supported+Packages)

Ultimately it sounds like you need to create NuGet (or similar) files containing your artifacts and get them up to Octopus!